# Need Sql query for returning true or false based on table unique column value

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables one master and one child and both contains a unique column field i need to return a false if child table contains a value other than master table value in unique column field .

- Table 1: Master (Master always contains only one row)
- Unique Column is PLID and Value is 10

Case: 1

- Table 2: Child
- Unique Column is PLID

it contains 3 rows

```
PLID
====
10
20
30
```

Then it contains other than master table PLID unique field values so I need to return False

Case: 2

- Table 2: Child
- Unique Column is PLID

it contains 3 rows

```
PLID
====
10
10
10
```

Case 2 contains Values same as in master table so need to return True

Need a function for this in SQL.

Comment: If the child table can have the same value repeated three times, then it can't be a unique column...

Comment: Sql Server .....

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

The original question was tagged with `sql` (referring to ANSI SQL) and this answer uses standard ANSI SQL.

However it turns out, the DBMS being used is SQL Server and that does not support `boolean` expressions like that. This answer **will not work** with Microsoft SQL Server.

But I'm leaving the answer nonetheless for reference.

---

You can use a co-related sub-query with a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
select plid, not exists (select *
                         from child_table ct
                         where ct.plid <> mt.plid) as has_no_other_values
from master_table mt;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/EYWXLQ53937

Comment: @Agnes: that's ANSI standard SQL (and you only added the `sql` tag which does not refer to a specific DBMS product). Apparently the DBMS you are using (which you did not tell us) does not support standard SQL in that way.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to find any rows that exist in one table but not the other.

You can then use an `EXISTS` clause to check if that query return any rows or not.

Many SQL dialects don't have boolean types though, in which case you could then wrap it all in a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN
    EXISTS (
      SELECT *
        FROM table_child   c
   LEFT JOIN table_parent  p
          ON p.PLID = c.PLID
       WHERE p.PLID IS NULL
    )
  THEN
    0
  ELSE
    1
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case
    when 
    (select Count(select 1 from childTable as c where c.PLID = (select PLID from masterTable) )) = (select Count(*) from childTable)
    then 'True'
    else 'False'
    end
```

Comment: can you please give this query without templ table insertion

Comment: @Agnes Edited without temp table !

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.plid, case when p.plid is null then 0 else 1 end as match
from child c
left outer join parent p in p.plid = c.plid
```

Select from child and join it to parent, matching parent to child with the same plid. However, 'left outer join' will return child rows where no matching parent is found. From that lot, where parent plid is null - that is, a matching parent row was not found - show 0 else show 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another option not mentioned before is to use the `LEFT JOIN` condition togheter with `IF(ISNULL)`.

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(child.PLID,1,0))
FROM table_parent parent
LEFT JOIN table_child child ON child.PLID != parent.PLID
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

select count (*) from
(select max(ChildPKID) as ID from Child where MasterPKID = 800
group by PLID)s